# How to solve fatal exception error in android studio

Tags: javascript, android, database, firebase, fatal-error

I have created an android APP and tried to run test on it for various devices, after running tests to several devices, some of them brought no errors, but in some devices I got a fatal error with the followings

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.schools.mackhandy/com.schools.mackhandy.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.schools.mackhandy, PID: 18210
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.schools.mackhandy/com.schools.mackhandy.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2406)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:825)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:523)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:368)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.schools.mackhandy.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6013)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.schools.mackhandy:drawable/splash_logo" (7f070085)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070085 a=-1 r=0x7f070085}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2412)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2350)
    at android.content.res.HwResources.loadDrawable(HwResources.java:589)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:788)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:744)
    ... 20 more
```

Please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: Please post your xml layout

Comment: Your `splash_logo` is in the wrong folder. You need to move it to a non-versioned `drawable` folder; one that does _not_ end in `-v??`, like `drawable-v24/`.

Comment: @Mike M., thanks your solution solved my problem